# Ajax http request terminated error while installing a Drupal 8 site

Tags: ajax, 8, installation

I have installed WAMP Server for Postgresql and during the time of installation of Drupal (version 8), I got this error:

> Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects
>   (block.block.bartik_search,
>   core.entity_form_display.node.article.default,
>   core.entity_form_display.node.page.default,
>   rdf.mapping.comment.comment, rdf.mapping.node.article,
>   rdf.mapping.node.page, rdf.mapping.taxonomy_term.tags) provided by
>   standard have unmet dependencies in
>   Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 89 of
>   core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException.php).
>   Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('standard',
>   Array)
>   Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module',
>   'standard') Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, )
>   install_install_profile(Array) install_run_task(Array, Array)
>   install_run_tasks(Array) install_drupal(Object)

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for Drupal 8. Please report all bugs to the issue queues on Drupal.org. Thanks

Comment: You need to run: `composer update` in Drupal docroot to install missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The UnmetDependenciesException is something you get when Drupal tries to install a configuration that depends on other modules/configuration which are missing.

You shouldn't see this error installing one of the standard install profiles. My hunch is that the source to your errors is PostgreSQL which is not fully supported by Drupal 8 at this time of writing.

See more in the issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2157455 for running Drupal 8 on postgreSQL.